# Concrete cost difference if forms done yourself

Tags: concrete, rebar

Thinking about getting a 4 inch thick concrete slab poured for my back patio.  I was wondering if I dug everything out, made and set the forms, and laid the stone and rebar, would that be a significant savings on the total job cost?  The concrete guys would just have to show up, pour the concrete, and finish it.

Comment: Depends what they quoted you

Comment: What size patio?

Comment: Jack, 13' x 35'

Comment: You might ask about the middle ground: you do all the digging; they do forms, rebar/mesh, and the pour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best way to find out is to ask a concrete contractor.

One potential problem with doing what you're suggesting is that there probably won't be a workmanship/cracking warranty, as the concrete guys may not "approve" of the stone & rebar work you would do.

Comment: Yep, asking the contractor would probably be the best bet.

Answer (score 3):

Been there , done that. If you do it yourself ,it is the price of a few yards of concrete ; the truck must be able the reach the forms. Three guys can finish it easily ( I did it with my wife-mistake, but it got done). The forms must be well braced because the wet concrete puts pressure on them.Because it was a patio, I did not use rebar .I did put in mesh ,make sure it is below the surface by more than an inch.At the last minute I had to rent a scred ?; a bar that reaches across and slides along the top of the from. I was going to use a 2 X 4 but the driver said it would not work. Driver was very helpful, for this flat work , the concrete I ordered needed to have a lot more water- not as hard to level. After it starts to set , be sure to "broom"it to roughen the surface or you will have an ice rink every time it gets wet ( a friend made that mistake). Go watch some concrete flat work being poured .

Comment: You can't do part of the job, either all or nothing. Can't you just imagine ;" the job is messed up because the forms were wrong"?

Comment: Sounds like you did it all yourself.  I would just want to do the prep work, then everything after the concrete gets poured in would be handled by the concrete guys.

Comment: The point is ; if you do anything and there is any problem , it was your fault.